# Can't keep session continuous between all pages using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session

I have created a session in php where users log in and their data is transferred in all the pages.it looks like this

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
include 'cw-config.php';
if($_SESSION[userid]!='')
{
$details=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from register where guid='$_SESSION[userid]'"));
}
?>
```

It works on all pages except on this one even though i wrote the code in same manner as above one.it looks like this:

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include 'cw-config.php';
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($_SESSION[userid]!=''){ 
$details=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from register where guid='".$_SESSION["userid"]."'"));
}
$shopdata=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from shop where guid='$shopid'"));
?>
```

Kindly visit:http://rewardsinn.com
the problem is with categories/stores when selected from dropdown menu the session isn't getting transferred
I am new to this coding and had redo everything as we were cheated by a designer.it was working fine till yesterday.Kindly help me in this.Once sign in and check to know the problem.
When we go directly the session is getting transferred..check after login:http://rewardsinn.com/deals.php?shopid=1

Comment: Take off the `session_start()` on this page.

Comment: Not working..i dont understand even though i am using same for all pages its not working only for this

Comment: when clicked through old code(by designer) its opening properly see this after login:rewardsinn.com/index3.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the problem pertains to sessions? I mean, have you tried retrieving the value of $_SESSION['userid'] directly (may be on screen for debugging sake).

If you have, does it help to use the function session_start() function before the ob_start() function? Usually it is required that session_start be called before any other statement (either HTML and PHP statements). So you might give it a try.

Comment: Not working...its taking it as a different session even though i am giving same code.kindly help me in this

Comment: when clicked through old code(by designer) its opening properly see this after login:rewardsinn.com/index3.php